# Remap an array to have an object above each entry in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, prisma

I have a prisma query that returns users on a pivot table CommunityMember. The pivot table associates to the table User. As a result, my queries into the User table do not place the object user on top of the replies. I have a lot of functions designed to run with the user object on top so I am trying to figure out how to map user into my returns so the functions can run correctly. I've tried a lot of combinations of map and have had no luck. Do you all have any ideas?

Here is my prisma query:

```
        members = await prisma.user.findMany({
            select: {
                id: true,
                username: true,
                name: true,
                bio: true,
                avatar: true,
            },
            skip: 10 * Number(page),
            take: 10,
        });
```

It gives a result like

```
members:
 [{id: 2, username: 'man}, {id: 3, username: 'dan'}]
```

I want it to look like: members:

```
members:
[{user: {id: 2, username: 'man'}}, {user: {id: 3. username: 'dan'}}]
```

If I run members[0].user I should get the data inside. It seems like a simple map function, but I have not been able to get it to work.

Another example of what I get, but do not want.

```
members:  [
  {
      id: 2,
      username: 'man',
      name: 'A Man',
      bio: 'A man.',
      avatar: [Object]
  },
  {
      id: 3,
      username: 'dude',
      name: 'Dude',
      bio: "Dude is a #1 developer.",
      avatar: [Object]
  },
```

This is what I want.

```
members:  [
  {
    //Notice the user object on top of each entry
    user: {
      id: 2,
      username: 'man',
      name: 'A Man',
      bio: 'Man.',
      avatar: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    user: {
      id: 3,
      username: 'dude',
      name: 'Dude',
      bio: "Dudes a #1 developer.",
      avatar: [Object]
    }
  },
]
```

Comment: So you just want to nest your object in an object with the key of `user`?

Comment: You should add the code for the attempted solutions to your question so we can debug them.

Comment: That said: `const out = members.map(obj => { return { user: obj }; });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I got the whole picture but wouldn't this do?

```js
    const members = [
      {
          id: 2,
          username: 'man',
          name: 'A Man',
          bio: 'A man.',
          avatar: {}
      },
      {
          id: 3,
          username: 'dude',
          name: 'Dude',
          bio: "Dude is a #1 developer.",
          avatar: {}
      }
    ].map(member => ({user: member}))
```

Comment: I tried it this way the first time and it did not work. After seeing your comment and trying it again I realized where I messed up. I basically did members.map(member=>(user: member)) and forgot to save it properly. I just needed to do members=members.map(member=>(user: member))

Comment: I accepted yours as the answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

if your object looks like:
`obj = {members: [{...}, ..]}`

then an [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will solve the problem:

```
const userMembers = obj.members.map((member) => ({user: member});
obj.members = userMembers;
```